# Haskell stack build FLTKHS after changes

Tags: haskell, ghci, fltk, stackage

Busy discovering Haskell libs. Found FLTKHS for GUI building. Its example `fltks-hello-world` works great as a skeleton for discovering the all the lib has to offer. However: when changing anything in the source file (`fltkhs-hello-world.hs`), does one need to `stack build` it all over? GHCi doesn't seem to grasp the FLTKHS imports, so the REPL is IMO no viable option. Interested in your way of working to learn....

Answer (score 0):

Found out that future builds are way quicker. Not as fast as GHCi though...